# Lenovo T495 - External screen keeps waking up laptop's screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, hdmi, amd-graphics, lock-screen

I tried searching the web for my issue, but Google and other platforms keep showing solutions for people not being able to wake up their screens, whereas what I'm looking for is kind of the opposite.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad T495 (AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3500U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile).
I connected a Iiyama screen to it, on the HDMI port; configured as a secondary screen extending the desktop.

Here is my issue: Whenever I lock my session (Windows + L), Ubuntu displays briefly the lock screen on both screens, and they both go black. Which works as expected.
However, from this moment, the following loop starts:

1. Laptop's screen is OFF, external screen is OFF and probably looking
   for a signal. This lasts for 10 seconds approximately.
2. Laptop's screen wakes up displaying Ubuntu's lock screen, external screen wakes up too a couple of seconds later. This lasts for 15 seconds approximately.
3. Because nothing's moving, Ubuntu shuts down screens again which go black.
4. ... and we're back at 1. above. This keeps loopi,ng for ever, both screens turning ON and OFF every 10 seconds or so.

Note: If I unplug the external screen, the Laptop's screen behaves as expected: When locking the session, it simply turns OFF and stays OFF until I move the mouse or type a key.

I really can't figure out what's wrong, it's as if the external screen was sending a signal when it got disconnected, which is interpreted as an input or something by the system...

Any idea? ^^'
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround** : The Workaround provided by this thread [Monitors do not turn off (enter powersave mode) after screen blanking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167445/monitors-do-not-turn-off-enter-powersave-mode-after-screen-blanking) *does* solve the issue.

But ideally IMHO, it would be better not to have to change screen's configuration, I guess...

That will do for now though :)